# How does 初めて work with location?

Tags: grammar

Example from this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0611.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_001):

> 先月、**東京都内で初めて開かれたセミナー**は、企業の人事担当者など200人余りで満員となり、注目の高さを伺わせた。日本は、アメリカに比べて、人事部門にデータ分析を専門的に行える人材が少なく、活用は大幅に遅れているという。

How do we know if it is:

1°)the first time that the seminar is held in 東京都内 ( but the seminar is not really new and has already been held in the past in other locations)

2°) The first time that the seminar is held in any location and the  location is 東京都内

I would like to know how to do 1°) if it is 2°) and how to do 2°) if it is 1°)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ambiguous sentence which can be interpreted in both ways. From the context, I believe the author meant 2 because the article clearly says this seminar is a new one held by a new organization. If the sentence were 東京都内で**は**初めて, it would only mean 1.